# How to draw a simple fixed width full page table?

Tags: tables, arrays

I would like to generate pages of memory from a script and I think LaTeX is the perfect tool to build a nice PDF. However, I am struggling with the table environment and I don't know how to design the following model (drawn with Illustrator).

The difficulties are:

- Fixed width columns and rows (array of 32 x 32 cells on a 163 x 260 mm table)
- Rotated top headers with no lines
- Bold headers with no lines
- Table border bolder than the internal lines

What I currently did is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{helvet}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\else
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,240mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=10mm,
}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{}>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule[0pt]{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[0pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

\newcommand{\TBstrut}{}

\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{PAGE 0x01000}
\newcommand\w{0.3cm}

\begin{tabular}{r|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|C{\w}|}
    & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}}& \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}}& \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}}& \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}} & \rot{\textbf{0x00}}\\
    \hline

    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{0x00000}} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\

    & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline


    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \TBstrut\\
    \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve that I would like?

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you (seriously) expect any of your readers to actually study the contents of a typeset 32 x 32 array?

Comment: Yes I expect that. My students have hard time to understand memory. I feel that the best solution to make them feel it is to write a typeset of 512 kiB with arrays, structures, text in Unicode and ascii, pointers and so on. I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By (a) switching from a `tabular` to `tabularx` environment, (b) reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` from 6pt (the default) to 1pt, and (c) reducing the value of `\arrayrulewidth` to 0.25pt, is *just* possible to squeeze all 33 columns into the available space. Note that it's not necessary to reduce the fontsize of the text. Finally, I would set the value of `\extrarowheight` to `2pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand{\rt}[1]{\rot{\textbf{#1}}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,240mm},left=20mm,top=10mm}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\fi

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\section*{PAGE 0x01000}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}    % default: 0pt
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.25pt} % default: 0.4pt
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}         % default: 6pt

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} r |*{32}{C|} }
& \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} 
& \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} 
& \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} 
& \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} 
& \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} 
& \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} 
& \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} 
& \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00} & \rt{0x00}\\
    \hline

    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{0x00000}} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\

    & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{0x00000} & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table is huge, so it is hart to fit to defined `\textwidth`, i. e. table content should use font size of  `\footnotesize` and `\scriptsize` for column headers. For simple defining table width as well cells width is selected `tabularx` table environment.

MWE consider only `XeLaTeX` engine, and font `Helvetica` scaled to 0.92.

**Edit (1):**
Now is removed vertical lines between rotated nodes as well as horizontal lines in the first column and left (border) line of the first column.

**Edit (2):**
Now is corrected small glitch in defining `\rotheadsize`. So far its measurement was considered word 0x00, which is not the longest in column headers. This can be fixed with adding empty space (and not searching for the longest one) or find the longest word (it seems that are 0x04 and 0x6). This correction enable to use font size `\small` for body and column headers. Using this font size make table a bit to wide, consequently it is needed to further reduce `\tabcolsep` (to 0pt) and add small space between the first and the second column. This changes are in the code marked by `% <---`.

**Edit (3):** For bold fonts in outer column and row the font definitions are changed to

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
```

(anticipating that for compilation is used only XeLaTeX)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[total={170mm,240mm},
            left=20mm,
            top=10mm,
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}            % <---
\renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\RH[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rothead{#1}}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\section*{PAGE 0x01000}
\begingroup
\small                                     % <---
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont 0x00 }  % <---
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}                  % <---
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} r!{\ \vrule width 0.6pt}   % <---
                        *{31}{C|}C!{\vrule width 0.6pt}}
\RH{}   & \RH{0x00} & \RH{0x01} & \RH{0x02} & \RH{0x03}
        & \RH{0x04} & \RH{0x05} & \RH{0x06} & \RH{0x07}
        & \RH{0x00} & \RH{0x01} & \RH{0x02} & \RH{0x03}
        & \RH{0x04} & \RH{0x05} & \RH{0x06} & \RH{0x07}
        & \RH{0x00} & \RH{0x01} & \RH{0x02} & \RH{0x03}
        & \RH{0x04} & \RH{0x05} & \RH{0x06} & \RH{0x07}
        & \RH{0x00} & \RH{0x01} & \RH{0x02} & \RH{0x03}
        & \RH{0x04} & \RH{0x05} & \RH{0x06} & \RH{0x07}\\
    \Xcline{2-33}{0.6pt}
0x00000 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 
        & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 
        & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \cline{2-33}
0x00000 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03
        & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03
        & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\ 
    \cline{2-33}
0x00000 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03
        & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03
        & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \cline{2-33}
0x00000 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03
        & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03
        & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
    \Xcline{2-33}{0.6pt}
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is much simpler than what I wrote. How to remove the borders on the header lines?

Comment: oh, I overlooked this. I will correct this asap.

Comment: @nowox, I edit answer and a bit improved solution (now use `\small` fonts.